# Displaying array on page, getting duplicated results - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, addeventlistener, array.prototype.map

I am making a simple to do app and am stuck on updating the data array when a new task is added. Right now, if you add a new task, the entire array re-populates on the display and duplicate values are listed. How do I resolve this so that only one iteration of the array displays any time it is updated on the page?

```
const completedDivs = document.getElementById("completed");
const taskDivs = document.getElementById("tasks");
const addBtn = document.querySelector(".fa-plus");
const input = document.getElementById("newTask");

// SET UP DEFAULT TO DO TASKS
let todos = [
  { completed: false, task: "Make Coffee", id: 1 },
  { completed: false, task: "Walk the dog", id: 2 },
  { completed: true, task: "Make calculator app", id: 3 },
];

// SET UP REQUIRED VARIABLES
let taskNo = (completedDivsLength + taskDivsLength) + 1;

// MAP OUT DEFAULT TASKS TO DISPLAY
function generateToDo() {
  todos.map(todo => {
    // CREATE A NEW DIV
    let newTask = document.createElement("div");
  
    // GIVE THE DIV AN ID
    newTask.id = `div${taskNo}`;
    
    
    if(todo.completed) {
      // FORMAT THE DIV
      newTask.innerHTML = `<input type="checkbox" id="task${taskNo}" checked>
      <label for="task${taskNo}">${todo.task}</label>
      <i class="far fa-trash-alt" id="trash${taskNo}"></i>`
      
      // Check the item off the list
      newTask.classList.add("checked");
      // Add the task to the completed list
      completedDivs.appendChild(newTask);
    } else if (!todo.completed) {
      // FORMAT THE DIV
      newTask.innerHTML = `<input type="checkbox" id="task${taskNo}">
      <label for="task${taskNo}">${todo.task}</label>
      <i class="far fa-trash-alt" id="trash${taskNo}"></i>`
      
      // Uncheck the task from the list
      newTask.classList.remove("checked");
      // Move the task to the To Do list
      taskDivs.appendChild(newTask);
    }
  
    // INCREMENT THE TASK NO BY 1
    taskNo++;
  });
}

// ADD NEW TASKS
addBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  todos.push({ completed: false, task: `${input.value}`, id: taskNo });
  generateToDo();
  // RESET THE INPUT FIELD TO NOTHING
  input.value = "";
});

// AUTOMATICALLY LOAD THE DEFAULT TO DOS
window.onload = generateToDo();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not iterate on the whole array each time a task is added.
Just create an element for the new task.
Only in on load iterate over the array.

```
// MAP OUT DEFAULT TASKS TO DISPLAY
function generateToDo(todo) {

    // CREATE A NEW DIV
    let newTask = document.createElement("div");
  
    // GIVE THE DIV AN ID
    newTask.id = `div${taskNo}`;
    
    
    if(todo.completed) {
      // FORMAT THE DIV
      newTask.innerHTML = `<input type="checkbox" id="task${taskNo}" checked>
      <label for="task${taskNo}">${todo.task}</label>
      <i class="far fa-trash-alt" id="trash${taskNo}"></i>`
      
      // Check the item off the list
      newTask.classList.add("checked");
      // Add the task to the completed list
      completedDivs.appendChild(newTask);
    } else if (!todo.completed) {
      // FORMAT THE DIV
      newTask.innerHTML = `<input type="checkbox" id="task${taskNo}">
      <label for="task${taskNo}">${todo.task}</label>
      <i class="far fa-trash-alt" id="trash${taskNo}"></i>`
      
      // Uncheck the task from the list
      newTask.classList.remove("checked");
      // Move the task to the To Do list
      taskDivs.appendChild(newTask);
    }
  
    // INCREMENT THE TASK NO BY 1
    taskNo++;
}

// ADD NEW TASKS
addBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const newTodo = { completed: false, task: `${input.value}`, id: taskNo };
  todos.push(newTodo);
  generateToDo(newTodo);
  // RESET THE INPUT FIELD TO NOTHING
  input.value = "";
});

// AUTOMATICALLY LOAD THE DEFAULT TO DOS
window.onload = todos.forEach( todo => generateToDo(todo));
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need these couple of lines - delete what is already there and then update

```
// MAP OUT DEFAULT TASKS TO DISPLAY
function generateToDo() {

    [].forEach.call(completedDivs.children,(x)=>x.remove());
    [].forEach.call(taskDivs.children,(x)=>x.remove());


  todos.map(todo => {
    // CREATE A NEW DIV
    let newTask = document.createElement("div");
  ...
```

Comment: That almost works. It seems to work on the completed section but not the uncompleted section. Weird. I'll play around with it some more though because it sure looks like you're on to something.

Comment: @redliz5808 could you give html so that I can figure it out to the end